# Uniformly convergent subsequence cos

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

I've been studying some problems in sequences of functions in "Berkeley Problems in Mathematics" chapter 1.6, and I have some difficulties understanding the solution to the following problem:

We are given a sequence of functions: $f_n(x)=\cos nx$. Prove that this sequence has no uniformly convergent subsequence.

To prove it, the author assumes that such a subsequence exists $f_{n_{j}} \rightarrow f$ uniformly. This means that $f$ is continuous and so $f(0)=lim_{j \rightarrow +\infty}\cos 0 =1$.

Hence there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $f(x)>\frac{1}{2}$ for $|x|<\epsilon$.
($f(0)=1$ and $f$ is continuous so in a certain neighborhood of $0$ $f(x)>\frac{1}{2}$ - is this the reason?) .

And this is what I don't understand:

$|f(x)-f_{n_{j}}(x)|<\frac{1}{2}$ for $x, \frac{\pi}{2n_j}<\epsilon$.

I know that uniform convergence of $f_{n_{j}}$ implies the inequality but why this assumptions about $x$ and $\frac{\pi}{2n_j}$?

Could you explain that to me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you're right, by continuity of $f$ at $0$, there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(0)|<1/2$ for $|x|<\epsilon$. Hence
$$
f(x)=f(0)+(f(x)-f(0))\geq f(0)-|f(x)-f(0)|>f(0)-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2} \quad\forall |x|<\epsilon.
$$

Now by uniform convergence, there exists $n_j>\frac{\pi}{2\epsilon}$ such that $\|f-f_{n_j}\|_\infty\leq \frac{1}{4}$. In particular 
$$
\left|f\left(\frac{\pi}{2n_j}\right) \right|=\left|f\left(\frac{\pi}{2n_j}\right) -f_{n_j}\left(\frac{\pi}{2n_j}\right)\right|\leq\frac{1}{4}
$$
since $f_{n_j}\left(\frac{\pi}{2n_j}\right)=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=0$. But as we took $n_j$ large enough to have $\frac{\pi}{2n_j}<\epsilon$, we also have
$$
f\left(\frac{\pi}{2n_j}\right) >\frac{1}{2}.
$$
Contradiction.

Comment: Thanks. By the way, I've also seen this $\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \ \ \underset{t \rightarrow x}{lim} \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{lim} g_n(t) = \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{lim}  \underset{t \rightarrow x}{lim} g_n(t)$ as a consequence of $g_n$'s uniform convergence. Could you tell me why that is?

Comment: Well, on the left, replace $\lim g_n(t)$ by $g(t)$ the (uniform) limit. And on the rhs, replace $\lim_{t\rightarrow x}g_n(t)$ by $g_n(x)$ by continuity of $g_n$. So the rhs is actually $g(x)$. And all this says is that $\lim_{t\rightarrow x}g(t)=g(x)$. That is, $g$ is continuous at $x$. In other words: the uniform limit of a sequence of continuous functions is continuous. Apparently, you already know that! The typical proof is an $\epsilon/3$ argument.

Comment: @Jakebb You're welcome, Jakebb.